# Add a border to BalloonMarker for iOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Usually I would add a border to a view like..

```
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 236.0 / 255.0, green: 91.0 / 255.0, blue: 110.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

But I can not see where I would go about adding that here.

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Objective-C/Components/BalloonMarker.swift

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep yet to add a comment.  So I have to put my question in an answer.  It looks like you are defining a path and calling `context.fillPath()`. Can you call `context.setStrokeColor()` after `context.setFillColor()`, then call `context.strokePath()` when you are calling `context.fillPath()`?  You may need to call `context.replacePathWithStrokedPath()` before stroking.

Comment: i can. but i dont see an options for adding a width for the stroke.

Comment: context.setLineWidth(CGFloat) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding the following into BaloonMarker.swift file:

First, add border color right after `context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)` inside `draw()` func inside that file:

```
context.setStrokeColor(borderColor.cgColor)
```

Then, edit stroke width if needed right before filling the context:

```
context.setLineWidth(borderWidth)
```

and finally make sure to replace `context.fillPath()` with following:

```
context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
```